# How can I load a third-party ML model into a serverless function

Tags: python, lambda, scikit-learn, serverless-framework

I have built an ML model (using the sklearn module), and I want to serve it predictions via AWS API Gateway + Lambda function.

My problems are:

1. I can't install sklearn + numpy  etc. because of the lambda capacity limitations. (the bundle is greater than 140MB)
2. Maybe that a silly question, but, do you know if there are better ways to do that task?

I've tried this tutorial, in order to reduce the bundle size. However, it raises an exception because of the --use-wheel flag.

https://serverlesscode.com/post/scikitlearn-with-amazon-linux-container/

```
    bucket = s3.Bucket(os.environ['BUCKET'])
    model_stream = bucket.Object(os.environ['MODEL_NAME'])
    model = pickle.loads(model_stream)
    model.predict(z_features)[0]
```

Where z_features are my features after using a scalar

Answer (score 0):

Just figure it out!

The solution basically stands on top of the AWS Lambda Layers.

I created a sklearn layer that contains only the relevant compiled libraries.
Then, I run `sls package` in order to pack a bundle which contains those files together with my own handler.py code.

The last step was to run
 `sls deploy --package .serverless`

Hope it'll be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to serve your sklearn model, you could skip the hassle of setting up a lambda function and tinkering with the API Gateway - just upload your model as a pkl file to [FlashAI.io](https://flashai.io) which will serve your model automatically for free. It handles high traffic environments and unlimited inference requests. For sklearn models specifically, just check out the [user guide](https://flashai.io/guide) and within 5 minutes you'll have your model available as an API.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this service